# a sql command why it shows an error?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$categories_query ="SELECT p.products_id 
,  p.products_quantity
, p.products_price 
, p.products_status 
,p.products_image
, pd.products_name

FROM products_description AS pd
INNER JOIN products AS p
ON p.products_id = pd.products_id
WHERE  p.products_status = 1 and p.products_id <> $pid and pd.products_name LIKE CONCAT(LEFT('$products_name',10),'%')";
```

some pages are running ok, even if there is no relative items. but when the `$products_name` is `A Bug's Life "Multi Pak" Special 2003 Collectors Edition`. it shows an error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Life "Multi Pak" Special 2003 Collectors Edition',10),'%')' at line 11
in:
[SELECT p.products_id...
```

why? and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example value of $products_name contains ' symbol, so sql query is messed up.

At the moment part of your query would be something like that

... (LEFT('Bug's Life "Multi Pak" Special 2003 Collectors Edition',10) ...

Note that an ' between g and s "ends" the first apostrophe and the rest of the $products_name is not a string value in executed query.

You should use prepared statements instead. You should also google "sql injection attack" for the vulnerabilities of your current code.

EDIT: you could use either

- mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

I'd personally prefer PDO. For reasons see [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: You should use prepared statements instead? how should i do? thank you

Comment: @dreamchaser I updated an answer with links to code examples.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use mysql_real_escape_string() on $product name. the " ' " is reason for that error, and mysql_real_escape_string() will fix that. You should always filter all variables before sending them to mysql, otherwise you are risking mysql injection trough malicious sql codel.
[mysql_real_escape_string() on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)